# Drupal 8 folder is empty after running docker-compose

Tags: docker, drupal, docker-compose, drupal-8

I'm trying to create a local development for Drupal 8. Here is the content of my docker-compose.yml file.

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - "./drupal/web:/var/www/html"
      - "./drupal/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"
    depends_on:
      - php      
  php:
    image: drupal:8.6-fpm-alpine
    volumes:
      - "./drupal/web:/var/www/html"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mysql
  mysql:
      image: mysql:8
      entrypoint: ['/entrypoint.sh', '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password']
      environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "drupal"
        MYSQL_USER: "drupal"
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: "drupal"
        MYSQL_DATABASE: "drupal"
      volumes:
        - "./drupal/mysql:/var/lib/mysql"
```

If I replace the volumes of the drupal, then it created drupal content under drupal container. However, after that I cannot access the drupal content from the host machine.

```
      - /var/www/html/modules
      - /var/www/html/profiles
      - /var/www/html/themes
      - /var/www/html/sites
```

After running **docker-compose up**. I support to have the content of drupal under drupal/web folder. However it is empty. Do you know what happened to it? Thanks,

Comment: Are you mounting the content from the host to the container ?

Comment: Yeah. I want to mount the content to host in order to edit it. Is it impossible?

Comment: Here is the log for drupal container:

`
docker logs drupal8_php_1                                                                                                                                                1 ↵  143  16:18:40
[20-Mar-2019 20:18:27] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1
[20-Mar-2019 20:18:27] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
`

Comment: The content should be under `/var/www/html` inside the container not drupal/web as you are mounting **from** `./drupal/web` on the host **to** `/var/www/html` inside the container

Comment: Yeah, I what I thought, but it's that path is empty inside the container. If I replace the volumes parameters (updated above), then it will generate the Drupal content. It's weird.

Comment: I have submitted an answer, check it below

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the volumes definition, according to [this](https://hub.docker.com/_/drupal/), it seems that you have to declare them as you described in your updated question.

> There is consensus that /var/www/html/modules, /var/www/html/profiles, and /var/www/html/themes are things that generally ought to be volumes (and might have an explicit VOLUME declaration in a future update to this image), but handling of /var/www/html/sites is somewhat more complex, since the contents of that directory do need to be initialized with the contents from the image.

So you need to define each path as a volume separately either a local directory or using named volumes, for example:

```
docker run --name some-drupal --network some-network -d \
    -v /path/on/host/modules:/var/www/html/modules \
    -v /path/on/host/profiles:/var/www/html/profiles \
    -v /path/on/host/sites:/var/www/html/sites \
    -v /path/on/host/themes:/var/www/html/themes \
    drupal
```

Regarding the permissions issue that's because the container changing the owner and the group to `www-data` as shown in [here](https://github.com/docker-library/drupal/blob/master/8.6/fpm-alpine/Dockerfile#L53) which might be using a different UID/GID than your actual host user. From the Dockerfile of drupal:

```
RUN curl -fSL "https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/drupal-${DRUPAL_VERSION}.tar.gz" -o drupal.tar.gz \
    && echo "${DRUPAL_MD5} *drupal.tar.gz" | md5sum -c - \
    && tar -xz --strip-components=1 -f drupal.tar.gz \
    && rm drupal.tar.gz \
    && chown -R www-data:www-data sites modules themes
```

What you can do is to set ACL rules from your host on drupal's files for example like below so you can edit and modify the files while developing (assuming that your username is **dale**):

```
sudo setfacl -Rm u:dale:rwx,d:u:dale:rwx /path/to/drupal/files
```

And of course if you create a file manually from the host, you need to give it a proper permission so the webserver can access it (assuming that www-data uid is 33 and gid is 33) by executing the command below:

```
sudo chown 33:33 /path/to/drupla/files_or_directories/ -R
```

Comment: Thanks, Mostafa for the information. I ended up writing script to manually update the Drupal 8 on the host machine. It still works with an extra step.